# Pandas convert datetime string column to datetime without offset applied

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm new to Python and Pandas, so dont be hard with me :)

I have multiple Columns in the form of "`2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00`". Now i want to convert the columns name into a pandas datetime. But i struggle with the format i need to use. I already tried

```
date = pd.to_datetime("2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

But here i get a error with `"ValueError: time data '2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z' (match)"`

I dont want the time to get converted into my timezone. I need it for the Timezone -06:00

For this Input:

> 2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00

The Output should be:

> 2014-01-01 00:00:00

I want to use the date variable of the Output so i can split my data into seasons. Something like this:

```
date > springBegining
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: `00:00:00-06:00` what time does this mean?

Comment: Hours:Min:Secondes and Timezone

Comment: Just FYI - if you have the month written as two digits (e.g. `01`, as in your code), you should write `%m` , not `%b`. You would use `%b` if the date was `"2014-Jan-01 00:00:00-06:00"`

Comment: So you want to remove the offset so make the timestamps all remove the offsets?

Comment: If all want all your timestamps to have time `00:00:00` you can just call `normalize` on the result

Comment: How does this work exactly? Im new to pandas

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00').normalize()` will give result `Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00')` but this will force all your time components to `00:00:00`

Comment: No, i have multiple times. But if i print the time, the timezone offsets converts the time of the colum name into my timezone (i dont want that)

Comment: Why not just remove the timezone from the string then? If the offset is the same you can just do `pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00'.rsplit('-',1)[0])`

Comment: You need to fully explain your problem, do all your timestamps have offsets and is the offset format always `'2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00'` or `'2014-01-01 00:00:00+06:00'`?

Comment: Yes all timestamps have the offset -06:00

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Nevermind, i made a small mistake, it works now. Thank you alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a format string, `pandas` is man/woman enough to handle this:

```
In[2]:
pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00')

Out[2]: Timestamp('2014-01-01 06:00:00')
```

besides your format string has numerous issues:

`%b` is month as locale abbreviated form, you have a numerical representation so it should be `%m`

`%z` requires a UTC offset in the form `'+HHMM'/-HHMM`

So you'd need to reformat the datetime string to:

`'2014-01-01 00:00:00-0600'`

If you don't want the offset to be applied and the offset is always the same you can strip this from the string:

```
In[25]:
pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00'.rsplit('-',1)[0])

Out[25]: Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Or you could slice the string:

```
In[26]:
pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00'[:-6])

Out[26]: Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00')
```

So to do the above on an entire column:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[col].str[:-6])
```

Example:

```
In[27]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00','2014-01-01 00:00:00+06:00']})
df

Out[27]: 
                        date
0  2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00
1  2014-01-01 00:00:00+06:00

In[28]:
pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str[:-6])

Out[28]: 
0   2014-01-01
1   2014-01-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Here we use the string accessor `.str` to slice all the columns in the same manner and pass this to `to_datetime` to convert the entire column

Comment: Yeah, this works, but i need the time for an other Timezone. If i only  use this like you suggest, i get the time convertet to my timezone.